# jquery / ajax login form flip over when loggin in or when login failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

i am using the following ajax and jquery script to login my users. The div element of the form will flip over when the user enters their login details and hits submit.

The code then checks for a succesfull login or a failed attempt.

Code:

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
var myusername = $("#myusername").val();
var mypassword = $("#mypassword").val();

if (myusername == null || myusername == "" || mypassword == null || mypassword == "") {
if (myusername == null || myusername == "") { document.forms["form"]["myusername"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
if (mypassword == null || mypassword == "") { document.forms["form"]["mypassword"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
$( ".home_column" ).effect( "shake" ); 
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("include/validate_login.php", {
username1: myusername,
password1: mypassword
}, function(data) {
if (data.indexOf("login_wrong") >= 0){
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h21>Incorrect Login Details</h21>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   $(".home_column").revertFlip()
  }, 2500);  }else{
  if (data.indexOf("login_fail") >= 0){
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            content:'<h211>Incorrect Password</h211><br/><h21>Forgot Your password?</h21><br/><div id="clicker">Try Again</div>'
})  

$('#clicker').live('click', function(e) {  
       $(".home_column").revertFlip()
    })

}else{
  if (data.indexOf("block_login") >= 0){
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h211>Account has been Blocked</h211>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   $(".home_column").revertFlip()
  }, 2500); }else{
  if (data.indexOf("login_blocked") >= 0){
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h211>Account Blocked</h211>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   $(".home_column").revertFlip()
  }, 2500); }else{
 if (data.indexOf("login_success") >= 0){
  $(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
        content: '<h211>Hello '+data.substring(13)+'</h211><div class="spinner"><div class="rect1"></div><div class="rect2"></div><div class="rect3"></div><div class="rect4"></div><div class="rect5"></div></div><h212>Preparing your Dashboard</h212>'    
}) 
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   window.location = 'dashboard.php'; 
  }, 4500);

  } } } } }
$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {   
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('keypress click', '#submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
});
});
</script>
```

My problem is in this section of code:

```
if (data.indexOf("login_fail") >= 0){
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            content:'<h211>Incorrect Password</h211><br/><h21>Forgot Your password?</h21><br/><div id="clicker">Try Again</div>'
})  

$('#clicker').live('click', function(e) {  
       $(".home_column").revertFlip()
    })
```

when  a user enters the correct username but the wrong password it returns with my data 'login_fail'

This tells the script that the user entered the correct username but the wrong password.

At this point the div flips round and asks if the user has forgotten their password and gives them the option to recover it. I also have a try again button which allows the user to flip the div back to the login form and try again.

I am struggling to try and trigger the revert flip call on a click function if the user clicks on my div id #clicker

please can someone show me where I am going wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().